# Serialize/Deserialize Binary Data

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I am writing a socket based application where i am required to **serialize and deserialize** data in **various data types such as string, integer, object (key-value pair of string and other data types) with a predefined length**. If you were me how would you go about achieving it ?

I understand that i haven't provided any code and that's because i couldn't think of an appropriate way to achieve what i wanted to do

Hopefully you guys would suggest me something.

**Data is formatted in the following way** :

$1 is a Boolean Marker where the next byte tells whether its true or false

$2 is a string marker followed by 16 bit integer which is the length of the string

$3 is an object marker = Data is stored in key value pairs where key is always a string and value could be string, boolean etc. Object type ends with $0 $0 $9

Comment: How are the data formatted ?

Comment: @Pierre I edited my post :)

Comment: If you have your own format then you need your own realization for it. However look at these links, maybe you will find its useful: [Protocol Buffers in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers), [Fundamentals Code Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fundementals/) contains Delphi/FPC code for protobuf.

Comment: @Abelisto  I know how to read the data it's just i don't know how to structure the data we read (through a class or a dictionary etc) in such a way that it could be passed back to the main class where i can read the decoded content based on the data type.

Comment: Can the objects be nested ?

Comment: Is so your format has a design flaw...I just say this but __$3<data>__ followed by __$3<data>__ doesn't allow to know if the second object is nested or at the same level. ;)

Comment: @Nestedtype This isn't my my own format it's adobe's and format.

Comment: Made a small typo I meant Amf* not "and"

Comment: @Spongebob , adobe ...you should put this as a tag, directly, to target the right people....yo!u know **pascal** is usually more system programming

Comment: What about MsgPack https://msgpack.org/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Do create class(es) declaring properties for all of your data and implement a converter which reads from the socket and populate object(s). Depending on the complexity of your data, implement an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) could be of some help.